# creating components

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I'm learning to create joomla components so is there any difference between joomla2.5 and joomla1.5 for creating components and modules as on the joomla official site documentation is about joomla1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_01
 You can find the tutorial of developing module in  Joomla 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are quite big differences.

First of all the install manifest has changed between 1.5 and 2.5, which means that components developed for 1.5 won't install on J2.5.

Secondly many Joomla classes has changed and some conventions are replaced by others. Check the Joomla API for the differences.